# Gtk-WARNING while open pdf from terminal

Tags: linux, shell, gtk

When I type command `evince foo.pdf` I got:

```
(evince:31753): Gtk-WARNING **: Allocating size to EvSidebar 0x55c8e3c17680 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
```

Then my terminal freeze to wait for something. I don't like this wait. I hope it can return the prompt as usual(do not wait so that I have to type ^C).

I have no alias on evince command.

I know that add `alias evince="evince &> /dev/null"` might remove this warning, but it will not work when I am not directly using this command in a terminal.

Is there other solution for this problem?

Comment: Your shell would normally wait for `evince` to exit. Is this what you are trying to avoid?

Comment: It's a bug from Gtk+. It's introduced sometime after Gtk 3.18. It hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: @JohnKoch: do you have a bug number to provide so this can be tracked by other users? Thanks.

Comment: Here's the commit related to this: https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/commit/?id=3e3f17576e07334e6c5be12fee9ed78f13f0cc24 . I found a lot of bugs downstream, but none upstream. It's a warning, but it seems to pollute traces a lot, so what causes the warnings should be fixed.